# MemberExpression: InvalidOperationExpression variable 'x' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm using [System.Linq.Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb506649.aspx)

I was attempting to build a simple [LambdaExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342202.aspx) that includes a [MemberExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.aspx). If I create the MemberExpression explicitly with the System.Linq.Expressions API (e.g. [MakeMemberAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.makememberaccess.aspx)), I will get the error "InvalidOperationExpression variable 'x' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined" when I call Compile() on the LambdaExpression.

For example ,this is my code

```
Expression<Func<Customer, string>> expression1, expression2, expression3;
Func<Customer, string> fn;
expression1 = (x) => x.Title;
fn = expression1.Compile();//works
fn(c);
MemberExpression m;
m = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x"), typeof(Customer).GetProperty("Title"));
expression2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, string>>(m,
    Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x"));

m = Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer),"x"), "Title");
expression3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, string>>(m,
    Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x"));

fn = expression3.Compile();//InvalidOperationExpression variable 'x' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
fn = expression2.Compile();//InvalidOperationExpression variable 'x' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

expression2 and expression3 throw an exception when the Compile() method is called, but expression1 does not; expression1 works. Why is this?  How do I create an MemberExpression like in expressions 2, 3 and get them to work (not throw an exception) when I call Compile()?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're creating *different* parameters called "x" several times. If you use a single `ParameterExpression`, it should all work fine.

```
ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x");
MemberExpression m = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(p, 
    typeof(Customer).GetProperty("Title"));
expression2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, string>>(m, p);

m = Expression.Property(p, "Title");
expression3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, string>>(m, p);

fn = expression3.Compile();
fn = expression2.Compile();
```

Basically parameter expressions aren't matched by name - you've got to use the same one everywhere. It's a bit of a pain, but there we go...