# Expression lambdas to access sub properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expression

I'm building a MVC HTML helper that exposes multiple properties of a class.

This is my class:

```
public class Foo {
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my helper:

```
public partial class FooBuilder<TModel> {
    public MvcHtmlString DropDownFooListFor( Expression<Func<TModel, Foo>> expression, string optionLabel = null, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null ) {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression( expression, Helper.ViewData );
        var model = metadata.Model as Foo;

        var items = FooUtility.GetFooValues( metadata.PropertyName ).Select( x => new SelectListItem {
            Text = x,
            Value = x,
            Selected = model != null && model.Value == x
        } );

        var value = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, string>>( Expression.MakeMemberAccess( expression.Body, typeof( Foo ).GetProperty( "Value" ) ), Expression.Parameter( typeof( TModel ), "value" ) );
        var list = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, string>>( Expression.MakeMemberAccess( expression.Body, typeof( Foo ).GetProperty( "Section" ) ), Expression.Parameter( typeof( TModel ), "section" ) );

        //Helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(
        //    Helper.HiddenFor( list, new { value = string.Format( "{0}#{1}", FooUtility.GetCurrentSection(), metadata.PropertyName ) } )
        //);

        return Helper.DropDownListFor( value, items, optionLabel, htmlAttributes );
    }
}
```

Then, inside my view, I call the helper

```
@(Html.Foo().DropDownFooListFor( x => x.Bar ))
```

And here is my view model:

```
public class Baz {
    public Foo Bar { get; set; }
}
```

---

My problem is that if I uncomment the three lines commented out (i.e: use the `list` expression), it miserably fails.

I don't get why using `value` works as expected but using `list` doesn't.

I get the following exception:

> variable 'x' of type 'Namespace.Baz' referenced from scope '', but it
>   is not defined

Again, `Baz` is my view model.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit**: Ok, this is worse that I thought. It works if I use any of my expressions with `DropDownListFor`, but it doesn't with `HiddenFor`, or `TextBoxFor`.

---

**Edit 2**: Here is how `Helper` is defined.

```
public partial class FooBuilder<TModel> {
    public HtmlHelper<TModel> Helper { get; set; }
}

public static class FooHelpers {
    public static FooBuilder<TModel> Foo<TModel>( this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper ) {
        return new FooBuilder<TModel> { Helper = helper };
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106283/memberexpression-invalidoperationexpression-variable-x-referenced-from-scope

Comment: @NickLarsen Where am I creating different parameters with the same name?

Comment: Out of curiosity, the commented out code is writing a hidden directly to the output, why are you doing that?  Also, can you update this code to show where the `Helper` is defined?

Comment: @NickLarsen, even though the helper is called DropDownFooListFor, it's supposed to render more than a drop down list. I just discovered that it's not a matter of how many times I use my expressions, but they just don't work with `HiddenFor` or `TextBoxFor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the two lambdas using the parameter which is in scope from the main expression (i.e. `expression.Parameters[0]`):

```
var value = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, string>>(
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
        expression.Body, 
        typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Value")
    ),
    expression.Parameters[0]
);

var list = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, string>>(
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
        expression.Body, 
        typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Section")
    ),
    expression.Parameters[0]
);
```

Now you can uncomment the `HiddenFor` call and it's gonna work.

Comment: Yeah this makes a lot of sense. Thank you Darin. Now I'm confused, do you have any idea why my expressions work with `Html.DropDownListFor`?

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding this correctly, the parameters to list and value were creating different expressions to get the same value, but they didn't have the context of the original expression?

Comment: @Bertrand Marron, the reason your code works with `DropDownListFor` is that you are never actually calling it inside this helper. You are simply returning an `MvcHtmlString` result from your helper and it is only inside the view that the `.Compile()` is invoked on the lambda by the `@` razor method. As far as the `HiddenFor` is concerned if you look carefully the `Write` method that you are using there on the `ViewContext` doesn't have an overload that takes an `MvcHtmlString`. It has one that takes `object`. This is what is used and `.ToString()` is immediately called... to be continued

Comment: ... and calling `.ToString()` eagerly invokes the `.Compile()` method on the lambda on this very same line, not in the context of the Razor view which is where the `x` parameter has been defined. This leads to a crash because you have created this `value` expression from `expression.Body` which itself requires the `x` parameter which is defined only inside the view. So the best way to overcome the issue is to simply use the same parameter as I did in my example.