# Expression.Lambda: Variable 'x' of type '' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, lambda

I saw connected [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106283/memberexpression-invalidoperationexpression-variable-x-referenced-from-scope) but...

I was attempting to implement specification pattern. If I create the Or or And Expression explicitly with the `System.Linq.Expressions` API, I will get the error

> InvalidOperationExpression variable 'x' referenced from scope.

For example ,this is my code

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> firstCondition = x => x.Id.Equals(2);
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> secondCondition = x => x.Id > 4;


Expression predicateBody = Expression.OrElse(firstCondition.Body, secondCondition.Body);
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> expr = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(predicateBody, secondCondition.Parameters);
Console.WriteLine(session.Where(expr).Count()); - //I got error here
```

EDITED

I tried to use [Specification pattern with Linq to Nhibernate](http://www.adamaldrich.com/blog/post/Specification-Pattern-and-Linq.aspx) so in a my work code it looks like:

```
ISpecification<Employee> specification = new AnonymousSpecification<Employee>(x => x.Id.Equals(2)).Or(new AnonymousSpecification<Employee>(x => x.Id > 4));
var results = session.Where(specification.is_satisfied_by());
```

So I want to use code like this x => x.Id > 4.

Edited

So my solution is

```
 InvocationExpression invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(secondCondition, firstCondition.Parameters);
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(firstCondition.Body, invokedExpr), firstCondition.Parameters);
Console.WriteLine(session.Where(expr).Count());
```

Thank you @Jon Skeet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of those bodies has a separate set of parameters, so using just `secondCondition.Parameters` doesn't give `firstCondition.Body` a parameter.

Fortunately, you don't need to write all of this yourself at all. Just use [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) by Joe Albahari - it's all done for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested, this is the Expression tree you have to use:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "x");
var firstCondition = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(param, "Id"),
        Expression.Constant(2)
    ),
    param
);
var secondCondition = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(
    Expression.GreaterThan(
        Expression.Property(param, "Id"),
        Expression.Constant(4)
    ),
    param
);

var predicateBody = Expression.OrElse(firstCondition.Body, secondCondition.Body);
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(predicateBody, param);
Console.WriteLine(session.Where(expr).Count());
```